# vscode: Go to Definition of functions within a namespace not working

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have a JavaScript file in visual studio code.  The Go to definition option works fine for functions defined on the global namespace i.e.

```
function myFunction(){
    //do something
}
```

But The Go to definition option does not work for functions defined within a namespace object I.e.

```
var MYNS = {};

MYNS.myFunction = function() {
    //do something
}
```

So if I have a call to MYNS.myFunction() I cannot Go to the definition.

Is it possible to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community with the  DocStubJS2017 extension and I am able to navigate to the function with Go to definition (F12). I have wrapped the namespace around the function.

```
var MYNS = {

   myFunction : function() {
       //do something
   }

};
```